# How to change values using multiple columns in pandas?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have 2 columns

```
Platform = [ Wii,Ds,Wii,3ds,GBA,GBA,3ds]

Year = [2006,2004,NaN,2011,1986,NaN,2012]
```

How do I change NaN value of Wii to 2008?

Answer (score 0):

If your dataframe is stored in a variable named `df` then this will work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [['Wii', '2006'], ['Ds', '2004'], ['Wii', np.nan], ['3ds', '2011'], ['GBA', '1986'], ['GBA', np.nan], ['3ds', '2012'], ['Wii', np.nan]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Platform', 'Year'])
df['Year'] = np.where((df['Platform'] == 'Wii') & (df['Year'].isna()), '2008', df['Year'])

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Platform  Year
0      Wii  2006
1       Ds  2004
2      Wii  2008
3      3ds  2011
4      GBA  1986
5      GBA   NaN
6      3ds  2012
7      Wii  2008
```

Comment: thanks,but lets say i have multiple Wii with NaN values all of them needs to be replaced with 2008..what do I do then?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions, but if you have a large number of data set I would suggest using NumPy vectorization [ref1](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-speedup-data-processing-with-numpy-vectorization-12acac71cfca), [ref2](https://medium.com/@mikeliao/numpy-vectorization-d4adea4fc2a), but here I am applying Pandas [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method:

1. find out the rows where platform is "Wii"
2. find out the column name that needs to be changed
3. check the value to which you need to be updated from (here with "NaN" value) with the updated value (2008)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
Platform = [ 'Wii','Ds','Wii','3ds','GBA','GBA','3ds']

Year = [2006,2004,np.NaN,2011,1986,np.NaN,2012]
df=pd.DataFrame({'platform':Platform,'year':Year})

print(df)

df.loc[df["platform"]=="Wii","year"]=df[df["platform"]=="Wii"]["year"].apply(lambda x:2008 if pd.isna(x) else x)


print(df)
```

Output:

```
platform    year
0      Wii  2006.0
1       Ds  2004.0
2      Wii     NaN
3      3ds  2011.0
4      GBA  1986.0
5      GBA     NaN
6      3ds  2012.0
platform    year
0      Wii  2006.0
1       Ds  2004.0
2      Wii  2008.0
3      3ds  2011.0
4      GBA  1986.0
5      GBA     NaN
6      3ds  2012.0
```